# Versioning in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, versioning, reindex

Solr by default overwrites any re-indexed document. But I want to save the old versions of updated documents.
 Is it possible  keep the previous versions of any document in the index? if not,please provide me with suggestions to do that.

Comment: How do you want old documents to behave? Be a regular part of the index, or have the option to roll a document back to a previous version? This will affect scoring/faceting/etc.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I want to keep access to previous versions of any indexed document

Comment: If you want to allow duplicate documents, you should regenerate the id of the document each time you're inserting it - by appending a version number, date stamp or something similar (so you have `id: <your-id>-3` or something similar). There's also a parameter you can give that allows Solr to have duplicate id's, but if you can avoid using that you'll be better off. You can also use a field checksum or something similar that uses the last update time (if you have such a field in your document). But as mentioned, be aware that this will return all versions of your document when searching.

Comment: Could you please provide me with useful resources to do that? all resources I found were to prevent duplication.

Comment: They work the same - just include the fields that will contain the version number / all fields where values are relevant in your list to generate the signature. That will give you a unique signature for documents that differ, in effect not de-duplicating anything.